# Multisite with different domain names on different servers

Tags: multisite, site-url

Consider the following servers with their domain names:

```
Server A:
   Domain A1 (Master Domain)
   Domain A2 (Addon Domain)

Server B:
   Domain B1 (Master Domain)
   Domain B2 (Addon Domain)
```

First, I setup a wordpress multisite on `A1` then I create a new site using a dummy subdirectory url and then edit the site and change the url to `A2`, then I go to cpanel and change root directory of `A2` to point to `A1` (where the multisite is). So far everything is okay, but  now I want to create a new site for the multisite under `B2`. Unfortunately, `B2` is on a different server, which means I can't simply change it's root directory to point to `A1`. What can I do? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Multisite assumes that all sites are on the same server. That's because it uses the same WP database for all of the sites. (Although the databases can get quite large if there are many sites, and lots of content. So you need to make sure the hosting server can handle large databases.)

So I don't see a way to do this (but I have been wrong before). If you wanted to spread the load, I guess you could have mirrored sites on both servers, and then use some sort of load balancing front end to send traffic to one or the other server.

If you are worried about the load factor of many sites, then just make sure that you have a hosting plan with lots of server horsepower. A basic 'sharing' hosting plan might get overloaded, depending on traffic and database size.

Comment: No, it's not about the load. These sites are all low traffic. I am just trying to make a multisite for someone who has these servers-sites.

Comment: I ended up moving `B2` Addon Domain under `Server A`.

Comment: That's probably the best choice, assuming that the multisite(s) are all owned by your friend. Not a big deal to put separate WP installs on different servers, if the purpose is to have separate content on both. Advantages to MS are that you can have common themes, plugins, and templates, so that a new site 'inherits' all of the settings of the 'master' site (by default). (If my answer was helpful, an 'accept' is helpful for others that may have the same question.